# Help in mounting/accessing part of a disk that is already being used

Tags: mount, disk, lvm

`lsblk` gives me this:

Screenshot of lsblk output

[image]

the volume hanging off sda3, 'ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv', contains the Ubuntu OS and runs well. What I don't have access to is to the rest of the 58.6G on sda3: ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv is listed when I run `df -h` but the rest of sda3 isn't.

Can somebody please give me some help in accessing the rest of the volume?

[k7aay](https://askubuntu.com/users/197910/k7aay) correctly suggests I edit:
This question relates to Ubuntu 20.04 Server. Would it be possible to expand the ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv volume to include the missing 58.6G?

Comment: Looks to me like you have not assigned a mount point for that partition. You can do that in /etc/fstab.

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: @user68186 my post was edited by another moderator who made no such comment. Is there a published list of 'preferences' I can read?

Comment: Some of it is written in the site [help](https://askubuntu.com/help). Some of it is in the [meta](https://meta.askubuntu.com/) questions and answers. All these and more can be accessed from the `(?)` icon on the top right corner of the web page.

Comment: @user68186 thank you. Shame you deleted your comment on my answer; my response to your comment is now left orphan and looks ridiculous.

Comment: Comments are just for clarifications and us trying to tell you if something can be improved. They are not meant for discussions. Many don't read them. If you think your response to my comment is important aspect of the answer, then please include it in the answer. The more complete the answer, better it is for others who may have the same problem in the future.

Comment: True, although my answer in the comments was in fact that your question in the comments was already included in the answer itself, which I presume is why you deleted your comment in the first place. Anyway, thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

The great people over at DigitalOcean helped me answer my own question, specifically in their article [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-lvm-to-manage-storage-devices-on-ubuntu-16-04).

The answer was to expand the logical volume I had to fill the available space, and the command I used was:

```
sudo lvresize -L +54G --resizefs ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv
```

New screenshot of lsblk output

[image]

Comment: Yes, the DigitalOcean article makes no mention of having to stop or otherwise modify the system before running the command so I didn't - I ran the command successfully with the system running.